# How do I unlock new hideouts?

Tags: watch-dogs

In Watch Dogs, you start out with two hideouts you can fast-travel to.  However, both are on the far corner of the island, so if I want to travel to a different corner, I have to make the long drive there manually.

I assumed I'd get more hideouts through missions or something, but I'm about 5 hours in and still have just the two.  **What do I need to do to unlock new hideouts?**  Also, how many are there total, and where are they?

Answer (score 8):

You unlock new hideouts by hacking ctOS towers. They are shown on the map as a red icon.
[image]

Comment: Not all ctOS towers grant a hideout, however. Of 5 towers I've cleared so far, only 4 unlocked a hideout. Though, admittedly, it's possible I need to advance in the main story for that 5th hideout to unlock.

Comment: I believe there's around 1-2 hideouts per area, but more towers in some areas, so the don't all unlock hideouts, but they unlock other areas of interest on minimap, so it's still useful to hack.

Comment: **Could you make a list of which towers unlock which hideouts?**  I've hacked several towers but haven't unlocked any new hideouts *(I must be getting really unlucky with my choices)*

Comment: Unfortunately, for me to do that I would have to restart the game. In my experience the first tower in an area (surrounded by a blue line on a map) usually unlocks a hideout, I don't know if I'm really lucky or that's just how it works. I will consider starting a new game to make a list, but I can't promise it to be soon.